# Silent login on Microsoft Azure AD with the ADAL library

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

We have an `IOS app` that uses `Azure AD` with the `ADAL library`. First time an administrator does the initial setup of the device. So it logs the user in with their credentials and they are stored locally onto the device.

The device then goes to a person who does not know the credentials for the login. What we want to do now is when the access token and refresh token are invalid the prompt is not shown to the user but that there is some sort of silent login.

The problem now is that when we look into the `ADAL library` we are able to pass a userId but not a password.

You guys have any idea if this is even possible and maybe point me out in the good direction.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Steaphann, have you tried the service to service way (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) to get a token ? i thin you must use another oAuth2 Library instead of ADAL to get an access_token. But in this solution i ended up in an error, you can see in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308689/get-request-failed-with-401-azure-using-adal-o-auth2-service-to-service

Answer (score 0):

Neither iOS or Android versions of ADAL support the use of programmatic username password sign-in.

Comment: is there some way exist in JavaScript to programmatic username password sign-in?